# Почему в сказках у Петушка золотой гребешок?

Tags: фольклор, литература

Есть ли какое-то объяснение тому, что в сказках гребешок Петушка часто называют золотым, хотя на самом деле он красный? Я как-то спрашивала об этом, выдвигались разные версии. Интересно узнать ваши мнения и предположения. Спасибо!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Петушок-золотой гребешок – это его имя: «Жили-были кот, дрозд да петушок— золотой гребешок…» И сказка эта – русская народная (хотя и в литературной обращаются к фольклорной традиции), а там у нас есть и Золотой петушок, и Баба Яга-костяная нога, и Колобок, и золотое яйцо, и конь у чуда-юда о двенадцати крылах, шерсть у коня медная, хвост и грива железная. 
Вот и выходит, что был у того петушка золотой гребешок, на то он и сказочный, не обязательно равнять его с настоящими петухами, хотя пород с жёлтыми гребешками встречается довольно много. 
А для русского народа характерно называть всё необычное золотым, солнечным. Нужно подходить к русской народной сказке, учитывая народные традиции, рассматривать их с точки зрения ритуалов, обрядов, представлений народа о жизни. В сказке говорится о смене дня и ночи. Петушок — это солнышко. Лиса подходит к окошку и зовет его (в народной культуре было очень много закличек к солнышку). Потом хватает и несет за высокие горы, за дремучие леса, за синие моря — путь неоправданно далек, т. е. это путь, который проделывает солнце. Лиса — это ночь, которая украла солнышко, а кот — утро, он вернул его. 
 Золотой у петушка гребешок, солнечный – так народ придумал. А что современные художники его красным рисуют – их дело, они ж в сказки не верят. Хотя у нас и солнце «красное». Мы ж не рисуем его красным, рисуем жёлтым, хотя кто-то видит и красным.

Comment: Людмила, Вас просто заслушаешься) Чудесный рассказ!

Comment: Полностью согласна с предыдущим комментарием! Спасибо огромное Вам, Людмила! Очень интересно!  Про сказку не знала.   
Что касается гребешка, то мне казалось, что он похож на корону, а она обычно из золота, желтая, вот и получилось, что у Петушка золотой гребешок. Кто-то предположил, что раз золото бывает и красным (точнее, красноватым), то, может, и гребешок подобен  короне из красного золота.   
О  "красном солнышке". Думаю,  что здесь "красное" в значении "красивое"

Answer (score 10):

У него еще и масляна головушка да шелкова бородушка. Многовато будет для собственных имен. Это эпитеты.
Самым дорогим золотом на Руси считалось червонное, с примесью меди. Оно вполне себе красного цвета (я опускаю некоторые профессиональные ювелирные подробности, различающие червонное и собственно красное золото). Этим и объясняется то, что многие красные предметы называли золотыми. От золотых яблок до тех же петухов.

Красно солнышко - это тоже не очевидный факт, что красивое, хотя такая трактовка напрашивается.  Обратите внимание, что солнце нигде и никогда не называли золотым. Хотя казалось бы, по всем критериям подходит. У меня даже насчет девицы есть бааальшие сомнения, что она - красивая. Красота не была главным достоинством девицы, а если уж говорили о ней, то конкретно - "Ах, боярыня красотою лепа, бровями союзна...". Думаю, что и в красном солнышке и в девице закрепилось еще одно старинное значение - пригожий, ладный, годный. Отсюда же и всякие "не красна изба углами, а красна пирогами". Но тут я не буду особо настаивать, личное мнение.

Comment: Если бы сейчас описание коня чуда-юда увидел уфолог, он бы тут же объяснил, что так в русском фольклоре объясняли контакты в ротшельцами))))))

Comment: Ну да, кто во что верует - на том стоит. 
Но я верую еще и в бритву Оккама, которую вот уже третий или четвертый раз поминаю за непродолжительное время. Ищи самое простое объяснение - не ошибёшься. Уфологам и пришельцам этого не понять.

ЗЫ А вот убедительных версий происхождения самого слова "чудо-юдо" я не знаю.

Comment: @behemothus  Масляна **головушка**, шелкова бородушка...

Comment: ну да. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Уверен, что это было взято из тюркских традиций, где во многих тюркских языках цвет "красный" и золото отмечались одним словом. И, когда было сближение с татарами,эта традиция перешла  и на русский язык. Отсюда и золото стало "червонным". ИМХО, конечно.

Comment: Тюрки исторически всегда были рядом, со времен Киевской Руси, а часто просто жили вперемешку, Канев на Киевщине был печенежским, огромная часть тюрков просто ассимилирована более сильными славянами. Взимные заимствования - дело естественное и неизбежное.

Comment: Вот и я об этом же. Только не понятно кто и за что поставил "минус" ))((